# Widgets appear with mouse over

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I would like a widget to be invisible until the mouse cursor is over it.

Using shinyjs I can make a widget show / hide when the cursor enters an 'Area'. However I would like to place the widget in the Area so to speak. Is this possible?

As far as I have got:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(

 ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(), 
    p(id="Area","Area"),   
    selectInput("A_widget", label = "A widget", choices=c("None"), selected="None")   
 ),

 server = function(input, output) {
    shinyjs::hide("A_widget")
    onevent("mouseenter", "Area", shinyjs::show("A_widget"))
    onevent("mouseleave", "Area", shinyjs::hide("A_widget"))
 }

))
```

I would like something like this pseudocode with the widget in the mouse over 'Area':

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(

 ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(), 
    p(id="Area", selectInput("A_widget", label = "A widget", choices=c("None"), selected="None"))
 ),

 server = function(input, output) {
    shinyjs::hide("A_widget")
    onevent("mouseenter", "Area", shinyjs::show("A_widget"))
    onevent("mouseleave", "Area", shinyjs::hide("A_widget"))
 }

))
```

I would like a widget that appears with mouse over. Thanks!

Comment: An alternative I'm open to is having the onevent() react to the widget itself and instead of using hide/show just recolor the whole thing white to make it 'invisible' and then return to the correct color when the mouse is over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a div with dimensions:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(), 
    div(id="Area", style = "width:300px;height:50px", 
        selectInput("A_widget", label = "A widget", choices=c("None"), selected="None"))
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    shinyjs::hide("A_widget")
    onevent("mouseenter", "Area", shinyjs::show("A_widget"))
    onevent("mouseleave", "Area", shinyjs::hide("A_widget"))
  }

)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Saved me loads of time. Much appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: Is it possible to display an image on mouse hover?